# Dependent component can't be instantiated in AbstractModel with Pyomo >= 5.7.3

Tags: pyomo

The following code does work on Pyomo 5.7.0, but does not work on Pyomo 5.7.3 and above anymore. The Error is "ValueError: Error retrieving immutable Param value (battery.n_time_steps)" (full traceback at the end) when trying to build the `time_steps` set.

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo


def test_param_pyomo5_7():
    def create_battery():
        block = pyo.Block()
        block.n_time_steps = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers, doc='Number of time steps')
        block.time_steps = pyo.RangeSet(1, block.n_time_steps, doc='Time steps')
        return block

    def create_model() -> pyo.AbstractModel:
        model = pyo.AbstractModel()
        model.battery = create_battery()

        return model

    data = {
        None: {
            'battery': {
                'n_time_steps': {None: 24},
            },
        }
    }
    
    model = create_model()
    instance = model.create_instance(data=data)
```

The full traceback is:

```
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py:697: in create_instance
    instance.load( data,
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py:734: in load
    self._load_model_data(dp,
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py:787: in _load_model_data
    self._initialize_component(modeldata, namespaces, component_name, profile_memory)
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\PyomoModel.py:825: in _initialize_component
    declaration.construct(data)
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py:2207: in construct
    obj.construct(data.get(name, None))
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\disable_methods.py:116: in construct
    return base.construct(self, data)
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\set.py:2792: in construct
    args = tuple(value(arg) for arg in args)
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\set.py:2792: in <genexpr>
    args = tuple(value(arg) for arg in args)
pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx:153: in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
    ???
pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx:138: in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value
    ???
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\param.py:853: in __call__
    return self[None]
..\..\opt\Miniconda3\envs\tesca_optimizer\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\indexed_component.py:577: in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_when_not_present(index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an inconsistency in how blocks were initialized from dictionary data in Pyomo<5.7.2, which was fixed in 5.7.2 (PR #1703).  The correct data dictionary requires "indices" for all components (even scalar components).  Your `data` dictionary is missing the `None` key (implicit index) for the data associated with the scalar Block `battery`.  The following data dictionary will work in recent versions of Pyomo:

```py
data = {
    None: {
        'battery': {
            None: {
                'n_time_steps': {None: 24},
            },
        },
    }
}
```